# Horizontal Text alignment in Word using OpenXml Sdk 2.0

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I need another help... My export function exports my report as a table in word. 
I need to apply horizontal alignment property for each cell. The Code I wrote for exporting is given below. Tbl is a textblock which I am using in my report.
I wrote Alignment code here. But doesn't works.. Please help me to accomplish this task using OpenXML SDk 2.0

```
 using Word = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

 WordprocessingDocument WordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(SavePath,  WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
 MainDocumentPart mainDocument = WordDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
 mainDocument.Document = new Word.Document();
 StyleDefinitionsPart StylesDefs = mainDocument.AddNewPart<StyleDefinitionsPart>();
 StylesDefs.Styles = new Word.Styles();
 Word.Body body = new Word.Body();
 Word.Table WordTable = new Word.Table();
 Word.TableRow Row;

 Word.TableCell Cell = new Word.TableCell();
 Word.Style ParaStyle = new Word.Style(new Word.Name() { Val = Tbl.GetHashCode().ToString() });
 Word.RunProperties ParaRunProperties = new Word.RunProperties();
 ParaRunProperties.Append(new Word.RunFonts() { Ascii = Tbl.FontFamily.ToString() });
 if (Tbl.HorizontalAlignment == HorizontalAlignment.Center)
     ParaRunProperties.Append(new Word.Justification() { Val = Word.JustificationValues.Center });
 else if (Tbl.HorizontalAlignment == HorizontalAlignment.Right)
      ParaRunProperties.Append(new Word.Justification() { Val = Word.JustificationValues.Right });
 else
      ParaRunProperties.Append(new Word.Justification() { Val = Word.JustificationValues.Left });
 ParaStyle.Append(ParaRunProperties);
 StylesDefs.Styles.Append(ParaStyle);
 Word.ParagraphProperties ParaProperties = new Word.ParagraphProperties() { ParagraphStyleId = new Word.ParagraphStyleId() { Val = Tbl.GetHashCode().ToString() } };
 Cell.Append(new Word.Paragraph(ParaProperties, new Word.Run(new Word.Text(Tbl.Text))));

  Row.Append(Cell);
  WordTable.Append(Row);
  body.Append(WordTable);
  mainDocument.Document.Append(body);
  mainDocument.Document.Save();
  WordDoc.Close();
```

Answer (score 8):

You should to use `w:jc` element for your paragraph (`w:p`) properties (`w:pPr`) to define your desired horizontal alignment:

```
<w:tr>
  <w:tc><!-- your table cell -->
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:jc w:val="right"/><!-- horizontal alignment = right -->
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Foo bar</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:tc>
</w:tr>
```

You always can to save a Word document as OpenXML, rename it to .zip and unpack it to inspect how to do something in OpenXML.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Rubens Farias,

My problem solved here.. Small Change in Code made it work.. Problem was I gave Justification property for Run Properties Instead Paragraph Properties.

I Changed Code as

```
Word.ParagraphProperties ParaProperties = new Word.ParagraphProperties() { ParagraphStyleId = new Word.ParagraphStyleId() { Val = Tbl.GetHashCode().ToString() } };
if (Tbl.HorizontalAlignment == HorizontalAlignment.Center)
     ParaProperties.Append(new Word.Justification() { Val = Word.JustificationValues.Center });
 else if (Tbl.HorizontalAlignment == HorizontalAlignment.Right)
      ParaProperties.Append(new Word.Justification() { Val = Word.JustificationValues.Right });
 else
      ParaProperties.Append(new Word.Justification() { Val = Word.JustificationValues.Left });
```

This Solved my Problem.. Once again Thanks for Rubens for your help, with which my mistake was Identified.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have three different kind of alignment inside your *Stylesheet*. You can use this constructor to pass it:

```
public Stylesheet(params OpenXmlElement[] childElements);
```

This is possible because *CellFormats* inherits from **OpenXmlElement**. In my code, I have created my own fill, font and border... don't pay attention to this if you don't need it.

```
new CellFormats(
                       //VALUE
                       // Index 0 - The default cell style - Alignment left
                       new CellFormat(new Alignment() { Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.Left, Vertical = VerticalAlignmentValues.Center }) 
                                     { FontId = 0, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0, ApplyBorder = true },

                       //HEADER
                       // Index 1 - Bold - Green background - align center
                       new CellFormat(new Alignment() { Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.Center, Vertical = VerticalAlignmentValues.Center }) 
                                     { FontId = 1, FillId = 2, BorderId = 0, ApplyFont = true, ApplyBorder = true, ApplyFill = true },

                       //ERROR HEADER
                       //index 2 - bold text - align center
                       new CellFormat(new Alignment() { Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.Center, Vertical = VerticalAlignmentValues.Center }) 
                                     { FontId = 1, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0, ApplyFont = true, ApplyBorder = true, ApplyFill = true }
               )
```

So, finally you can set your cell as a header in this way:

```
private enum CellStyleEnum
{
    Value = 0,
    Header = 1,
    Error = 2    
}

var cell = new Cell
{
    DataType = CellValues.InlineString,
    CellReference = header + index,
    StyleIndex = (UInt32)CellStyleEnum.Header
};
```