# get height and width of docx file without using office

Tags: c#, ms-word

I get count of pages in next code:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;

WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open( @"D:\2pages.docx", false );

Console.WriteLine(
    doc.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart.Properties.Pages.InnerText.ToString()
);
```

can I get in this way height and width of file?
or in another way but without using office.

Comment: What is “height and width of file”? Dimensions of pages? Note that, in general, a single Word document may contain multiple sections with different page dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Aspose.Word (which is not free) has these things built in:
https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/Changing+Page+Setup+for+Whole+Document+using+Aspose.Words

```
Document doc = new Document();

// This truly makes the document empty. No sections (not possible in Microsoft Word).
doc.RemoveAllChildren();

// Create a new section node. 
// Note that the section has not yet been added to the document, 
// but we have to specify the parent document.
Section section = new Section(doc);

// Append the section to the document.
doc.AppendChild(section);

// Lets set some properties for the section.
section.PageSetup.SectionStart = SectionStart.NewPage;
section.PageSetup.PaperSize = PaperSize.Letter;
```

Someone had a similar problem and this is the discussion on SO (but with OpenXML):
[Change Page size of Wor Document using Open Xml SDK 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795528/change-page-size-of-wor-document-using-open-xml-sdk-2-0)
Maybe you can deduct your answer from this.

Comment: Do you have another answer without using with not free dll? Thank you for your tring!

Answer (score 0):

Please use PageSetup.PageHeight and PageSetup.PageWidth properties to get the page's height and width. Hope this helps you.

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "input.docx");

Console.WriteLine(doc.FirstSection.PageSetup.PageHeight);
Console.WriteLine(doc.FirstSection.PageSetup.PageWidth);
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: wich dll/ using/ reference I need in order to use with Document and MyDir words.Because I tried it, but my program didn't know this words.Thank you a lot for your tring! waitting to your answer-rachel

Comment: The reference DLL is [Aspose.Words for .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Words/) and MyDir is string variable.

Comment: Do you have another answer without using with not free dll?